# How do I separate the hashtags from a tweet?

Tags: ruby

What would be a good way to remove the hash-tags from a string and then join the hash-tag words together in another string separated by commas:

```
'Some interesting tweet #hash #tags'
```

The result would be:

```
'Some interesting tweet'
```

And:

```
'hash,tags'
```

Comment: What is the expected result for `Some #hash interesting tweet #tags`?

Comment: Why do this with a string? The Twitter API includes pre-parsed hashtags, including their locations in the tweet.

Comment: @DaveNewton it's entirely possible the tweets aren't being pulled from twitter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = 'Some interesting tweet #hash #tags'
a,b = str.split.partition{|e| e.start_with?("#")}
# => [["#hash", "#tags"], ["Some", "interesting", "tweet"]]
a
# => ["#hash", "#tags"]
b
# => ["Some", "interesting", "tweet"]
a.join(",").delete("#")
# => "hash,tags"
b.join(" ")
# => "Some interesting tweet"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate path is to use `scan` then remove the hash tags:

```
tweet = 'Some interesting tweet #hash #tags'

tags = tweet.scan(/#\w+/).uniq
tweet = tweet.gsub(/(?:#{ Regexp.union(tags).source })\b/, '').strip.squeeze(' ') # => "Some interesting tweet"
tags.join(',').tr('#', '') # => "hash,tags"
```

Dissecting it shows:

- `tweet.scan(/#\w+/)` returns an array `["#hash", "#tags"]`.
- `uniq` would remove any duplicated tags.
- `Regexp.union(tags)` returns `(?-mix:\#hash|\#tags)`.
- `Regexp.union(tags).source` returns `\#hash|\#tags`. We don't want the pattern-flags at the start, so using `source` fixes that.
- `/(?:#{ Regexp.union(tags).source })\b/` returns the regular expression `/(?:\#hash|\#tags)\b/`.
- [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) is an extremely fast way to translate one character or characters to another, or strip them.

The final regex isn't the most optimized that can be generated. I'd actually write code to generate:

```
/#(?:hash|tags)\b/
```

but how to do that is left as an exercise for you. And, for short strings it won't make much difference as far as speed goes.

Comment: He does not want `"#hash,#tags"`. He wants `"hash,tags"`.

Comment: @theTinMan, +1 all tweets are "short" strings :) Thanks for `Regexp.union`. I didn't know about that one.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The difference would be in long strings, when they're thousands of characters long, and even then it would be minor. `Regexp.union` is a great method when you need to search for multiple array elements. I use it all the time and you can find a bunch of examples where I've used it here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

This has an array of hash that starts out empty
It then splits the hash tag based off spaces
It then looks for a hash tag and grabs the rest of the word
It then stores it into the array

```
array_of_hashetags = []
array_of_words = []

str = "Some interesting tweet #hash #tags"

str.split.each do |x|
  if /\#\w+/ =~ x
    array_of_hashetags << x.gsub(/\#/, "")
  else 
    array_of_words << x
  end
end
```

Hope the helps